# What does this mean by saying "public–facing bite"？

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> She stood out by writing the way a woman’s internal monologue might actually sound, oscillating between **public-facing bite** and what are usually privately-held insecurities.

I read this in the Rolling Stone website, here is the link: https://www.rollingstone.com/music/music-features/sza-interview-new-music-950364/

Comment: Bite = cuttingly sarcastic comments. Public-facing = oriented toward the public. Public-facing bite = witty silent judgement of society. At least that's my interpretation.

Comment: Sounds like it just means crass or snarky.

Comment: What she says in  public, sarcastically, and what she says in public about her own insecurities, which normally would not be said that way.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to say exactly what people mean when they use unusual metaphors, leaving readers to interpret them as best they can.

But the writer is clearly making a distinction between the sentiments that people normally share with the public and those they generally keep to themselves.

S/he says SZA's lyrics deal with both her own personal insecurities and her public views. Unless the word **bite** is mistyped (and it's hard to imagine how) it suggests painful "truths" that hard to deal with.

Because **public-facing bite** is a new metaphor, other readers may well interpret it differently.